# The culture of erasing

Tags: discussion, support, moderators, deletions

It's seems that erasing answers/comments (maybe even questions?) is a common practice here on MY.

Personally I don't like this culture. I KNOW that some of my viewpoints will cause a few Rabbis to squeak/roll their eyes. That's fine. But here on the internet? I feel that erasing people opinions is inappropriate, which leads me to the next issue...

You don't like my opinion? great! comment!  downvote and comment! or better - show me I'm wrong! that's fine! why erasing?

Assuming that the culture of erasing will not change, can you please provide guidelines for posting? I've read the tutorial, and still some of my posts were erased.

Comment: See https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment for the purpose of comments. In particular, they're ephemeral by design, and moderators can and very often do delete them. Answers and questions are deleted much less often, but can be deleted by the community also, not only by moderators.

Comment: I see two questions here: "why erasing?" and "can you please provide guidelines for posting?". You may want to ask one here and the other separately so each can be addressed fully.

Comment: Could you [edit] in links to substantiate the last line of this post? From what I can tell, the only substantial post of yours that was deleted was deleted by you. In general, this post would be a great deal more compelling and addressable if you'd [edit] in some examples of specific deletions that you consider counter-productive.

Comment: @IsaacMoses Obviously, I can't link to deleted posts.. They're gone! And I don't talk about posts that I deleted myself.

Comment: You can link to posts that had the comments on them. Moderators can see them and quote then here if necessary with your permission.

Answer (score 6):

It's important to distinguish between question and answer posts on one hand, and comments on the other. Q&A posts are the primary content on Mi Yodeya, while [comments](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) are "temporary 'Post-It' notes left on a question or answer."

**Q&A Posts**

Question and answer posts get deleted relatively infrequently. Descriptions of how and why they can get deleted are in the pair of FAQ posts mbloch shared in his answer:

- [Why and how are some questions deleted?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-questions)
- [Why and how are some answers deleted?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers)

Generally speaking, there are two categories of reasons why we would delete a Q&A post:

1. The post does not do at all what that kind of post is supposed to do, i.e. question posts that don't pose a question at all relevant to this community, or answer posts that don't respond at all to the question at hand.
2. The content of the post [abuses the community](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/conduct) in some egregious way.

Besides the relatively high bar for deletion, the site privileges Q&A posts in another important way: posts deleted by the community can always be seen by their authors and some community members, can be improved by the people who can see them, and can always be undeleted. For example, you can see lists of every single question and answer you've posted, including deleted ones, [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/19474/alaychem?tab=questions) and [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/19474/alaychem?tab=answers). The deleted posts are highlighted in pink. At present, you have two deleted answers, one of which you deleted and one of which was converted to a comment by a moderator.

**Comments**

[Comments](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment)  are secondary to Q&A posts. They are meant to be temporary aids to improving whatever they're posted on. As such, they may be deleted at any time if they are not directed towards that purpose or if they have already served that purpose. They can also be deleted if they are abusive in any way or are inconsistent in any way with our [Code of Conduct](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/conduct). Secondary as they are, it's often not worth keeping comments around that are destructive to the community.

Moderators can view, edit, and undelete deleted comments. If you believe an comment of yours was deleted incorrectly or prematurely, you can appeal that action directly to the moderators by flagging the post it was on "for moderator attention," or you can bring it up here on Meta or in Chat.

Comment: If you have 10k, you can see your own deleted posts by searching for `user:current deleted:yes`.

Comment: @MonicaCellio You don’t need to use `user:me`, as `deleted:1` will automatically only return your own posts.

Answer (score 3):

These posts from the help center might help

- [Why and how are some questions deleted?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-questions)
- [Why and how are some answers deleted?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers)